# Como mover los espacios de un vector en c++?

Tags: c++, array, c

la cosa va asi:
Quiero mover los datos a la derecha a partir del ingreso de mi dato, sin importar el ultimo dato del vector, ingresando un determinado dato por ejemplo quiero ingresa en el 0 un numero 7 pero quiero que el 0 no se borre si no que pase a la casilla siguiente **sin punteros**

```
vector[7]={1,2,3,0,4,5,6}

resultado:

vector[7]={1,2,3,7,0,4,5}
```

El código

```
int pos=3;

for(int i=pos+1; i<7; i++){
    valor[i]=valor[i+1]
    // cómo le hago para dejar ese espacio donde ingresare el 7?
}
```

Comment: Si estamos hablando de un vector de C++, puedes usar la función `insert`.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que debes hacer es crear el hueco. Para ello desplazamos una posición los valores que se van a encontrar a continuación del nuevo valor:

```
for(int i=6; i>pos; i--){
    valor[i]=valor[i-1];
}
```

Hay que recorrer el array de derecha a izquierda para mover los valores correctamente. Si recorremos el array de derecha a izquierda pisaremos todos los valores del array (puedes hacer la prueba)

Ahora ya tienes el hueco hecho, es decir, si partíamos de este estado inicial

```
vector[7]={1,2,3,0,4,5,6}
```

Tras este bucle deberías tener:

```
vector[7]={1,2,3,0,0,4,5}
```

Lo que hay que hacer ahora es añadir el nuevo valor al array y listo:

```
valor[pos] = 7;
```